# using UIImage to load png image in landscape mode

Tags: uiimage, png, orientation, landscape

I have an app running in landscape mode (home button on right) I built long time ago using Xcode 4. It loads a 480 x 320 png file as background image and has been working well. Recently I updated my Xcode to 5 and the image is loaded in a portrait orientation not landscape anymore. I thought it was an Xcode compatibility issue and easy to fix first but couldn't find my way out and had to ask for some help here.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Xcode 5 sometimes disregards the settings for orientation when converting or interpreting an old project file. Find the place where you set the orientation for your target and set the orientation again explicitly.

Comment: I have tried to set device orientation in both project settings and programatically in the view controller. Neither helped. I think somehow the device orientation is not respected by the App.

Comment: Did you only do this in the project settings or also in the target settings (tab "General" section "Deployment Info")?.